# Strange behavior using useState to load data into a object state

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, use-state

i have broken my head trying to understand a problem with my code. I'm new with React Native so there may be a standard behavior that i am unaware of. This is my problem:

In my component i have a useEffect() to load my data like "componentDidMount":

```
useEffect( () => {
  async function loadDadosLista(){
    let listaRecebida = await getListaByID(route.params.idLista);
    setLista(listaRecebida);
  };
  
  loadDadosLista();
}, []);
```

My function works correctly, the function getListaById accesses my realm.db and return my object lista. After that I can access the data and associate it with components of type TextInput. My real problem is that any change the i do in any component using properties of lista, overwrites all data leaving only the one that has been modified. I'm using spread operator but apparently it doesn't work. Below is my complete code for better understanding.

```
function ListConfig(){
  const [lista, setLista] = useState({});

  useEffect( () => {
    async function loadDadosLista(){
      let listaRecebida = await getListaByID(route.params.idLista);
      setLista(listaRecebida);
    };

    loadDadosLista();    
  }, []);

  return(
    <View style={styles.container}>  
      <View style={[styles.containerLinha, styles.linha2]}>

        <View style={styles.inputLocal}>
          <TextInput
            name='estabelecimento'
            placeholder='Venda do seu Francisco'
            placeholderTextColor={theme.colors.cinzaPrimario}
            style={styles.textInputLocal(theme)}
            value={lista.estabelecimento}
            maxLength={25}  
            onChangeText={ (value) => {
              setLista({
                ...lista,
                estabelecimento: value
              })
            }}
            textAlignVertical='bottom'                              
          />
          <IconLocation width={20} height={24} />
        </View>
      </View>

      <View style={styles.containerNotif}>
        <Text style={styles.textoNotif(theme)}>
          Me notifique 20 minutos antes
        </Text>
        <ToggleSwitch
          isOn={lista.notificacaoAtiva}
          onColor={theme.colors.cinzaSecundario}
          offColor={theme.colors.cinzaSecundario}
          thumbOnStyle={{
            backgroundColor: theme.colors.destaque
          }}
          size="medium"
          onToggle={(isOn) => {
            setLista({
              ...lista,
              notificacaoAtiva: isOn
            });
          }}
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

export default ListConfig;
```

My object lista have this properties:

```
{
  estabelecimento: 'nameOfEstabelecimento',
  notificacaoAtiva: true
}
```